# R: fit mixed effect model

Tags: r

Suppose we have the following linear mixed effects model:
[image]

How do we fit this nested model in `R`?

For now, I tried two things:

1. Rewrite the model as:

[image]

Then using `lmer` function in `lme4` package to fit the mixed effect model and put `Xi` as both random and fixed effect covariate as:
`lmer(y ~ X-1+(0+X|subject))`

But when I pass the result to `BIC` and do the model selection, it always picks the simplest model, which is not correct.

2. I tried to regress `y_i` on `X_i` first and treat `X_i` as the fixed effect, then I will get the estimate of the slope, i.e. `phi_i` vector. Then see `phi_i` as the new observations and regress on `C_i` again to get the `beta`. But it seems not correct since we do not know `C_i` in the real problem and it looks like `C_i` and `beta` jointly decide the coefficients.

So, are there other ways to fit this kind of model in `R` and where are my mistakes?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks much more like a CrossValidated.com sort of question